# d3js: supply a function to tickPadding

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Say I have [a graph where the x-axis tick labels are very long strings](http://jsfiddle.net/6XPpe/2/), and so I want to alternate the tick padding (the vertical distance between the text and the x-axis) so that the tick labels don't overlap.

I know this can be achieved post-rendering by selecting the tick elements and applying a transform attribute.  But I'd like to do:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x0)
.orient("bottom")
.tickSize(0)
.tickPadding(function(i) {
  // some logic here to determine the alternating-height strategy by index, e.g.
  return i % 2 ? 20 : 30;
 });
```

This doesn't work in d3 as-is -- the documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickPadding) says that tickPadding just takes the number of pixels. Is there a better way to do this? Monkey patch d3's axis.tickPadding function to take a function or a number, then apply the function when drawing the ticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the source-code patch, see:

https://github.com/adonomay/d3/commit/bfdb36fa17806666775c6804b86eb10bea3b3393

An alternate fix is to wrap the text manually after rendering:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1641

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Answer (score 1):

I also was hoping to do this. I was using week numbers and it got a little cramped. Basically the x axis looked like

```
111213141516171819
```

and I was hoping to stack them. I ended up doing this

```
$('.tick text').each(function(i){
   var yval = this.getAttribute("y");
   if( i % 2 == 0 )this.setAttribute("y",parseInt(yval)+10);
});
```

Once the graph was drawn. I made sure to include some extra margin (10) on the bottom as well. The result was

```
  12  14  16  18
11  13  15  17  19
```

Comment: Thanks. We did something similar via d3 selection rather than JQ:

    xAxis.selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', function (d,i) {
         var y = i % 2 === 0 ? 10 : 0; // move the even ones down
         return 'translate(0,' + y + ')';
       });

Answer (score 0):

The only choice you have is to modify the source. D3 assumes throughout the axis implementation that `tickPadding` is a number, not a function -- see [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js).